# Unable to Delete Email Using Hotmail on IOS 6

Tags: mail.app, ios, hotmail

When attempting to delete emails in the Mail app using hotmail (exchange server) there is always the error: "the message could not be moved to the mailbox trash"

Messages used to delete just fine, but this error message is a recent problem.

Comment: If you try to file the messages into another folder, does that fail you as well? In the past we had to go [choose the deleted messages folder when it got unset](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS2475) and more recently, you had to see if there were IMAP settings with a root that you could set to INBOX… but I'm not sure these address the changes to outlook.com. I hate to suggest POP access, but that might be the only workaround at present...

Comment: are you trashing it locally or on the server?